# What does this response object mean? ( Zapier JS code )

Tags: javascript, integration, fetch-api, zapier

I have the following code in Zapier Code:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://<HOST>/api/v1/siteinfo",
  "method": "GET",
  "crossDomain": true,
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic <TOKEN>",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

fetch(settings.url, settings)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    var output = {id: 1234};
    callback(null, output);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
  callback(error.text());
};
```

which I've basically copied from [Zapier documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-http-example).

After running this request I get this response:

[image]

**Why there is lot's of data, some buffer contents etc. and not just simple `{id: 1234}` ?**

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides of this question:

**1. Why didn't the code work?**

**Currently** Zapier doesn't have straightforward way of telling that your code updates will not be in effect unless you will tell **Re-test Code by Zapier to get another run javascript** which can be found on **Test this step** item of Zap step.

[image]

Another way is to add some input parameter. This also make Zapier to reevaluate the code.

**2. What is the object I was getting?**

This is raw [Response Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) defined by [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). One need to parse it with some specific method like `.text()` or `.json()` as described in examples of Zapier prior to have it in *regular* format.